# Comment traduire « peer review » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Comment traduisez-vous le terme « Peer review » en français ?

Par exemple, lorsque l'on édite une question ou une réponse sur French Language & Usage beta et que l'on ne possède pas certains privilèges, on a un message stipulant que l'édition est insérée dans la *peer review queue* (Je ne me souviens pas du message exact).

Certains parlent d'*examination par des pairs*, d'autres de *remise en question* mais je trouve ces traductions pas tout à fait exactes. Je comprends la signification de ces deux termes mais n'arrive pas à trouver une traduction compréhensible par tous.

Comment: Je ne vois pas de réponse en général, mais ce cas précis, on a affaire à un mélange de supervision (supairvision?) et de modération... Dans les usages de *Peer review*, il y a aussi les corrections mutuelles entre élèves dans les évaluations formatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans le contexte de FL&U ou équivalent, on pourrait utiliser le terme de *révision par la communauté* ou de *vérification par la communauté*.

Ou bien faire recours à un néologisme du style *corévision* ou *covérification*.

Comment: (+1) J'aime beaucoup ce *corévision*

Comment: Merci, c'est le genre de réponse que j'attendais.

Comment: @Zistoloen Juste par curiosité, quelle réponse as-tu retenue?

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon: Dans le cadre de cette communauté, _révision par la communauté_ me plait bien. Dans un cadre général, je penche pour _corévision_ comme Romain VALERI.

Comment: J'aime des néologismes et des mots obselètes. +1 pour corévision.

Answer (score 9):

Pour un CV académique, on fait souvent référence aux publications dans des revues à comité de lecture. En anglais, on dirait *publications in peer-reviewed journals*. Cette tournure est utilisée, par exemple, dans les consignes du CNU pour les candidats aux postes d'enseignants-chercheurs.

Le CRSNG (Canada) fait référence à «l'évaluation par les pairs» (voir par exemple leur [FAQ sur le système d'évaluation](http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca/NSERC-CRSNG/FundingDecisions-DecisionsFinancement/Questions-Questions_fra.asp) pour les subventions de recherche). Wikipedia aussi: voir [Évaluation par les pairs](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89valuation_par_les_pairs).

Comment: « Revue » n'ayant rien à *voir* avec « *review* » ici :-) Par ailleurs, utiliser *revoir* pour traduire *review*, comme semblent le faire certains, ce serait un faux-sens.

Answer (score 8):

Pour faire simple et rapide, j'ai toujours entendu parler de *revue de pairs* ou de *revue des pairs* durant mes études, où j'avais certains enseignants-chercheurs qui l'utilisaient dans leur travail de recherche. Je continue à utiliser revue de pairs dans le cadre de mon travail en informatique, et ça passe très bien.

C'est surtout rapide et percutant.

Néanmoins, je suis déjà tombé sur un terme beaucoup plus élégant et finalement proche du sens de *peer review* en anglais, qui implique deux concepts, *évaluation* et *personnes qualifiées du domaine* : **le jugement des pairs**.

Traduire *peer review* par **jugement des pairs** reste court et percutant à mon sens, en plus d'être élégant (mais peut-être un peu trop guindé dans le contexte de FL&U).

Comment: Mon expérience confirme aussi que _revue de pairs_ est l'expression consacrée dans le milieu de la recherche scientifique.

Comment: Mon expérience infirme, on parle de relecteurs et on utilise le verbe relire, mais pour nommer l'action on anglicise et pour le procédé en général c'est l'« évaluation par les pairs ».

Answer (score 3):

Oui, j'ai aussi buté sur cette traduction plusieurs fois.

On a les approximations plus ou moins littérales que tu cites dans la question, voire *révision par les pairs* / *révision des pairs*, mais ce n'est pas forcément satisfaisant.

Sinon, même si le sens initial n'est pas exactement équivalent, j'ai souvent trouvé le terme **cooptation** suffisamment proche pour être une bonne solution, à valider cependant selon le contexte, bien entendu. Sur cette voie, on pourrait également imaginer d'autres idées... pourquoi pas aussi **examen collégial**, ou bien que pensez-vous de **coexamen** ?

Je proposerais aussi **relecture technique**... on s'éloigne de la traduction littérale mais il me semble qu'on traduit mieux l'idée.

Answer (score 3):

Est-ce que **évaluation**
(par les pairs, par les experts etc.) ne serait pas plus simple et plus correct que **examination** ?
Examination n'existe pas en français, par conséquent, on en arrive à traduire un mot anglais par... un autre mot anglais !!!

Comment: Oui, "évaluation par les pairs" est un terme couramment utilisé comme pointé par @SamuelLisi.

Answer (score 2):

...Bref,la plupart des réponses données ici sont correctes... mais (comme souvent) dépendent beaucoup du contexte: "cooptation" peut aller très bien pour désigner un forum auto-géré, mais aurait des connotations désastreuses en parlant du fonctionnement de la publication scientifique. On peut alors y parler de relecture par les pairs... mais ceci ne n'applique que quand il s'agit de choses a lire (review est moins focussé que relecture). évaluation par les pairs est pas mal en général.

Attention: cooptation, collégialité, confrontation d'experts laissent entendre une symétrie des rôles (le proposant figurant parmis les "co-examinateurs") alors que le peer review donne le pouvoir à des personnes (pas toujours toute la communauté: oui en forum, non en science) à l'exclusion du proposant. Réciproquement 'confrontation aux experts' perd l'idée que ce sont des pairs.

NB: en pratique en recherche on utilise souvent le terme anglais peer review, meme en Français (personnellement je n'aime pas trop qu'on veuille absoluement créer un néologisme pour les termes qui n'existaient pas déjà: quand l'académie française a voulu se mêler de traduire les termes informatiques ça a fait rire tout le monde). 
A ce propos, je vois proposées ici des traductions originales. Si elles ont leur mérite en soi, attention, elles ne correspondent pas pour autant à des usages consacrés (ce qui doit être pris en compte en traduction).

Answer (score 1):

*Une critique d'expertise* ou *une confrontation d'experts*.

Comment: Ne serait-ce pas (logiquement) plutôt une *confrontation **aux** experts* ? Parce que *confrontation d'experts* ça sonne un peu *combat des chefs*... non ?