# Translation of "scientific journal"

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, science

"Her article was accepted to a good scientific journal."

Should "journal" be translated with "journal" or "revue" in this context? I think "journal" in French is more like a diary or a newspaper, but "revue" is also more like a magazine. So should it be

> Son article a été accepté à un bon journal scientifique.

or

> Son article a été accepté à une bonne revue scientifique.

Comment: Do note that the french scientists I know *actually use* "journal" in (informal) french (as an anglicism, you may say), since it's well understood, and all science is so full of english words. See also [**peer review**](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6331/1514) and [**review**](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/8156/1514).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, "journal" is a diary or a newspaper. "Revue scientifique" is the right term in this case.

Moreover, I never heard about an article being "accepté".  I would rather say

> Son article a été **publié** **dans** une bonne revue scientifique

Also, the "bonne" adjective is not quite right.

> Son article a été **publié** **dans** une revue scientifique **crédible**

Maybe **prestigieuse**, **réputée** (based on the context)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why is "bonne" not right here?

Comment: Using *crédible* (believable) *prestigieuse* (prestigious) or *réputée* (famous) add extra information *bonne* doesn't have. These words are not interchangeable. Moreover *crédible* doesn't even imply "good". I would not trust a *revue scientifique crédible*, did you mean *fiable* (reliable) ?

Comment: technically, your article is "accepté" before being "publié", so that makes sense if you are speaking before the "revue scientifique" is published but after you know your article will be in it.

Comment: Can "respectable" also be used here?

Comment: "Respectable" is more about ethics and morals